# How to print specific element of a 2d array via searching for a matching value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a 2d array:

```
a = np.array[ ("words",3) , ("blah",7) , ("hmm",1 ]
```

and I have a value: `3.0`

How do I print the first index in the 2d array based off of the matching value?

desired output: `words`

Here's my code:

```
k = np.array([["words words ", 4], ["blah blah", 1], [" please help me", 9]])
a = []
for i in range(len(k)):
    holder = (int(k[i,1]))
    a = np.append(a, holder)
    print(k[i,1])
    print(a, 'a')

a = np.asarray(a)
print('')
print( a )
print('')

close = (np.abs(a - dot)).argmin()  # dot is the value 0, it is the value of previous dot product computation
print(close , "close")
c = close
print(a[c])
```

Comment: What kind of array is that? Are you sure it works? Shouldn't you create a list of tuples?

Comment: If your plan is to do numerical comparison and you're wedded to arrays, I would suggest using two arrays (so that one can be numerical and the other a string) and then use the zeroth index found by  `np.where` to index the string array. Otherwise Pandas is worth a look, and if your strings don't repeat a dictionary is a good fit.

Comment: Are you interested in the index or in the content of the array? Because based on your question it looks like you want as output the content of the tuple whose second element is equal to a certain number....

Comment: I am interested in printing the string that is coupled with the same number as the "value"

Comment: I made the array "a" that has all of the numerical values that are paired with the string values from array "k". I then find the closest value from "a" when compared to the value from "dot" which in this question is equivalent to the number 0. I then run a comparison with "close" to find the closest value to "close" that is stored in "a" 
my goal is to then retrace my steps a little and print the string value that is paired with the value returned from the last comparison between "close" and "a"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only interested in printing the string coupled with a specific number I'd do something like this:

```
a = [("words",3), ("blah",7), ("hmm",1)]
b = [c[0] for c in a if c[1]==3]
print(b)
>>> b
['words']
```

If you're then interested to look for a value that's as close as possible to a given value I'd do something like this:

1.Build an array `b` with all the numeric values in present in `a`

2.Create an array of tuples with the abs difference between the values in `b` and `dot` and their index

3.Find the min value in this last array and take the corresponding index in `b`

4.`b[index]` is the value to look for in `a`.

```
def search_element(dot):
    b = [c[1] for c in a]
    index = min([(abs(f-dot),i) for i,f in enumerate(b)])[1]
    n = b[index]
    b = [c[0] for c in a if c[1]==n]
    return b
```

Comment: This is definitely useful, but If I can't hard code this, how would I implement it? I am going to have a currently updated "dot" value, so it will be constantly changing

Comment: You mean like the function with the parameter `n` at the end of my answer? Or something else? Is your `dot` an integer value?

Comment: my dot is an integr value

Comment: If the dot value returns an 11, for example, the target value would then be 9, as it is the closest value in array "k" to the dot product value. I would then want to print the string that is paired with that 9

Comment: I cannot use the b = [c[1] for c in a]. it throws an IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable. Any way around this?